# .backward() functions allocates way too much GPU memory

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I'm new to pytorch and trying to train a model similar to x-clip using it. The training batch isn't large by any means and pytorch usually reserves around 1.5 GB of memory when it starts out and only around 200MB are allocated.

The problem is that after some epochs the .backward() functions suddenly tries to allocate around 2GB of memory and the reserved memory goes up to 5GB. This trends continues and over time .backward() function tries to allocate and reserve more and more memory, until i get an out of memory error.
I'm currently using pytorch 1.6.0
This is my code:

```
# Preprocessing
            masks = exps.mask.detach().clone().cpu().numpy()
            completed_videos = numpy.where(masks == 0)[0]
            video_info = numpy.array([[i // self.num_frames_per_proc, i % self.num_frames_per_proc] for i in completed_videos])
            
            num_samples = 0
            video_idx = numpy.array([], dtype=int)
            video_len = numpy.array([], dtype=int)
            max_len = 0
            
            if video_info.size != 0:
                for idx in video_info:
                    if idx[0] not in video_idx:
                        video_idx = numpy.append(video_idx, idx[0])
                        video_len = numpy.append(video_len, idx[1])
                num_samples = video_idx.shape[0]
                max_len = numpy.max(video_len) + 1
            # X-CLIP loss
            similarity_mx = torch.zeros((num_samples, num_samples), device=self.device)
            # video_matrix = torch.zeros(
            #     (num_samples, max_len, self.acmodel.instr_dim)
            # ).to(self.device)
            # video_global_embeddings = torch.zeros(
            #     (num_samples, self.acmodel.instr_dim), device=self.device
            # )
            # text_matrix = torch.zeros(
            #     (num_samples, exps.obs.instr.shape[1], self.acmodel.instr_dim)
            # ).to(self.device)
            # text_global_embeddings = torch.zeros(
            #     (num_samples, self.acmodel.instr_dim)
            # ).to(self.device)
            
            
            # build feature matrices
            env_start_index = video_idx * self.num_frames_per_proc
            all_indices = numpy.array(env_start_index) + numpy.arange(max_len)[:, None]
            all_indices = all_indices.T.reshape(-1)
            mem = exps.memory[all_indices]
            batch = exps[all_indices]
            output = self.acmodel(batch.obs, mem * batch.mask, mask=batch.mask)
            video_matrix = output["frame_embedding"].reshape(num_samples, max_len, self.acmodel.instr_dim)
            text_idx = numpy.arange(num_samples) * max_len
            text_matrix = output["token_embedding"][text_idx]
            text_global_embeddings = output["instr_embedding"][text_idx]
            del batch, output
            
            # pad videos
            for i in range(len(video_len)):
                video_matrix[:, video_len[i]+1:, :] = 0 
            video_global_embeddings = torch.mean(video_matrix, dim=1)
            
            #calculate similarity matrix
            for i in range(num_samples):
                for j in range(num_samples):
                    frame_token_similarity = self.Attention_Over_Similarity_Matrix(
                        torch.matmul(video_matrix[i], text_matrix[j].T), self.x_clip_temp
                    )
                    text_frame_similarity = self.Attention_Over_Similarity_Vector(
                        torch.matmul(video_matrix[i], text_global_embeddings[j]), self.x_clip_temp
                    )
                    video_token_similarity = self.Attention_Over_Similarity_Vector(
                        torch.matmul(text_matrix[j], video_global_embeddings[i]).T, self.x_clip_temp
                    )
                    video_text_similarity = torch.matmul(
                        video_global_embeddings[i].T, text_global_embeddings[j]
                    )
                    similarity_mx[i][j] = (
                        frame_token_similarity
                        + text_frame_similarity
                        + video_token_similarity
                        + video_text_similarity
                    ) / 4
            # calculate loss function and optimize
            x_clip_loss = self.loss_fn(similarity_mx) * self.x_clip_coef
            x_clip_losses.append(x_clip_loss.detach().cpu().item())
            
            scaler = GradScaler()  
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            pytorch_total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in self.acmodel.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
            print(pytorch_total_params)
            print("after append and zero")
            print("torch.cuda.memory_allocated: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.memory_reserved: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            scaler.scale(x_clip_loss).backward()
            print("after backward")    
            print("torch.cuda.memory_allocated: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.memory_reserved: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            scaler.step(self.optimizer)
            scaler.update()
            print("after step")    
            print("torch.cuda.memory_allocated: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.memory_reserved: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved(0)/1024/1024/1024))
            print("torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: %fGB"%(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(0)/1024/1024/1024))
```

I used prints to locate the line that causing the problem. Below is the output of the code:

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                                                                                                                                          │······················
8768056                                                                                                                                                                                     │······················
after append and zero                                                                                                                                                                       │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.166960GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 0.396484GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 0.396484GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 0.370296GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
after backward                                                                                                                                                                              │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.155167GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 0.396484GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 0.396484GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 0.370296GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
after step                                                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.155167GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 0.396484GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 0.396484GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 0.370296GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                                                                                                                                          │······················
8768056                                                                                                                                                                                     │······················
after append and zero                                                                                                                                                                       │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.184617GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 0.396484GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 0.396484GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 0.370296GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
after backward                                                                                                                                                                              │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.155358GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 2.457031GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 2.457031GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.243207GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
after step                                                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.155358GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 2.457031GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 2.457031GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.243207GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                                                                                                                                          │······················
8768056                                                                                                                                                                                     │······················
after append and zero                                                                                                                                                                       │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.185820GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 2.457031GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 2.457031GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.243207GB
```

and later again:

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                                                                                                                                          │······················
8768056                                                                                                                                                                                     │······················
after append and zero                                                                                                                                                                       │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.195668GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 2.457031GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 2.457031GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.244883GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
after backward                                                                                                                                                                              │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.155900GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.792890GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
after step                                                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.155900GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.792890GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$                                                                                                                                          │······················
8768056                                                                                                                                                                                     │······················
after append and zero                                                                                                                                                                       │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.197360GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.792890GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
after backward                                                                                                                                                                              │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.157592GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.794581GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
after step                                                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.memory_allocated: 0.157592GB                                                                                                                                                     │······················
torch.cuda.memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                      │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved: 5.056641GB                                                                                                                                                  │······················
torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated: 2.794581GB                                                                                                                                                 │······················
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

I tried deleting variables as i don't need them anymore and empty_cahce() but all it does is lowering the usage down to a reasonable amount only for it to spike again.

I also tries using autograd to convert the variables to float16 but it didn't help at all. The last i tried was commenting out the line where i add loss to a list thinking it could be the cause of leak to no avail.

The model only has around 8M parameters so i don't understand why it has to use so much memory to calculate gradient.